# Forwarding to an Aggregate Initializer?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

It seems to me that aggregate initialization (of suitable types) is not considered a constructor that you can actually call (except a few cases.)

As an example, if we have a very simple aggregate type:

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
};
```

then this obviously works:

```
auto p = new Foo {42, 17};  // not "Foo (42, 17)" though...
```

but this doesn't work on any compiler that I've tested (including latest versions of MSVC, GCC, and Clang):

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.emplace_back(2, 3);
```

Again, it seems to me that any code that wants to call the constructor for a type `T` (in this case, the code in `vector::emplace_back` that forwards the passed arguments to the c'tor of `T`,) cannot use aggregate initialization simply (it seems) because they use parentheses instead of curly braces!

Why is that? Is it just a missed feature (nobody has proposed/implemented it yet,) or there are deeper reasons? This is a little strange, because aggregate types by definition have no other constructor to make the resolution ambiguous, so the language could have just defined a default aggregate constructor (or something) that would have all the members as defaulted arguments.

Is it just a matter of syntax? If the implementation of `vector::emplace_back` in the above example had used placement `new` with curly braces instead of parentheses, would it have worked?

**Note**: I want to thank those comments who've pointed out the behavior of `vector` and `emplace` because their comments will be valuable to those who'll find this question using those keywords, but I also want to point out that those are just examples. I picked the most familiar and concise example, but my point was about explicitly calling the aggregate initializer in any code (or in `placement new`, more specifically.)

Comment: Great question. Just to add one thing - one can't simply change `emplace_back` to use `{}` instead of `()`, since it may break **a lot** of legacy code. Consider this example: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec{}; vec.emplace_back(10, 10);`. The behaviour changes drastically when you switch them up. +1 though on making `()` and `{}` behave the same regarding aggregates, unless someone points out some similar problems regarding them.

Comment: An aggregate is movable iff its members are. You are saving one set of moves at the cost of even more complexity.

Comment: From here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/
Inserts a new element at the end of the vector, right after its current last element. This new element is constructed in place using args as the **arguments for its constructor.**

You structure simple does not have any constructors with two arguments.

Comment: I was tempted to reply "whoosh..." to these comments; see the Note at the end of question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For what it's worth, [P0960 "Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values"](https://wg21.link/P0960) does exactly what it says. It seems to have [passed EWG](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2018/11/30/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-san-diego-november-2018/) and is on its way into C++20.

> aggregate types by definition have no other constructor to make the resolution ambiguous

That is incorrect. All classes have default constructors, as well as copy/move constructors. Even if you `= delete` them or they are implicitly deleted, they still technically have such constructors (you just can't call them).

C++ being C++, there are naturally corner cases where even P0960 does the "wrong thing", as outlined in the paper:

```
struct A;

struct C
{
  operator A(); //Implicitly convertible to `A`
};

struct A { C c; }; //First member is a `C`

C c2;
A a(c2);
```

The initialization of `a` is a case of ambiguity. Two things *could* happen. You could perform implicit conversion of `c2` to an `A`, then initialize `a` from the resulting prvalue. Or you could perform aggregate initialization of `a` by a single value of type `C`.

P0960 takes the backwards compatible route: if a constructor *could* be called (under existing rules), then it always takes priority. Parentheses only invoke aggregate initialization if there is no constructor that could have been called.

Comment: On your point about default/copy/move constructors, I'd say fair enough. And the example you quote about the ambiguity between the use of a copy-ctor and an aggregate initializer is one that wouldn't occur to me. I might be in a biased state of mind right now, but it's really hard for me to give any weight to that example as a real piece of code (besides, I think that only could happen to single-member classes, right? Yes, yes, I know that you can aggregate-init a multi-member class using a single value too.)

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out that paper. Since their proposal solves all my problems in this regard, I'm happy now. Just have to wait for the compilers to pick it up as well...

Answer (score 0):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Aggregate Initialization is not a constructor.

According to this document, you did not define any constructors and meet the other conditions for Aggregate Initialization. (Refer to the item "class type" in the section "Explanation") That means your code does not call something like automatically generated constructor of signature `Foo(int, int)` but it is just another feature.

The document says about its effect is:

> Each array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

As `vector::emplace_back(Args&&... args)` works this way and it cannot find such constructor.

> The arguments `args...` are forwarded to the constructor as `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.

So it does not find such constructor.

Thinking this way, it also makes sense that your code cannot compile `auto p = new Foo (42, 17);`.

One more example, if you write any kind of constructor(even `Foo::Foo() {}`), `auto p = new Foo {42, 17};` does not work. Because now it does not meet the condition for Aggregate Initialization.

As far as I know Aggregate Initialization also works in C which does not even support constructors.

Here's [a good article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/06/15/should-structs-have-constructors-in-cpp/) worth reading.

Comment: I think the OP understands that 1) the type is an aggregate, and 2) aggregates initialization isn't invoked by `()`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh you are right. I just wanted to say the aggregate initialization is not same kind with constructors. But I just read your answer now I am not sure on that. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, but P0960 is about giving users what they want and need. List initialization cannot be used non-locally (like in `emplace` machinery) in a safe way for a variety of reasons, and there's no way to tell `emplace` that you want to perform aggregate initialization. So instead, you just make a minor change to the language allowing `()` to invoke aggregate initialization if no constructor could be called.

Comment: So, would that mean even with P0960, it is still unable to call aggregate initializations from `emplace` methods?

Comment: I don't know how you read that from my comment. `emplace` machinery ultimately uses `()` syntax, so if `()` can invoke aggregate initialization, then `emplace` machinery would be able to invoke aggregate initialization.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!